# What is the proper usage of pbr for Python libraries?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-pbr

Many projects use pbr for automated tracking of changes and incrementing versions. Me too. My project is a library. (It is the Sphinx extension [sphinxcontrib.constdata](https://gitlab.com/documatt/sphinxcontrib-constdata) for completeness.)

Do I understand properly that my library also needs pbr as install_requires dependency?

But this means that all users of a lib, also need pbr to be installed. Isn't it a serious design flaw? pbr should be a build-time dependency, not runtime dependency and not required just for using a lib.

What is the proper usage of pbr for Python libraries?

Also, enabling the extension causes sphinx-build to crash with

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'sphinxcontrib.constdata' distribution was not found and is required by the application

and

> Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name
> sphinxcontrib.constdata was given, but was not able to be found.

exceptions.